# Test Class using File and FileInputStream with Mockito/PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I would like to mock a File and FileInputStream Object for an JUnit test.

Let us say we are having a Parser. From outside the Parser is just accessible via the parse(File myFile) method. The other methods like readMyStream....are private.

Example Code:

```
public class Parser {

   public HashMap<String, String> parse(File myFile) throws Exception {
         HashMap<String, String> myConfig;
         Config config;

         try {
             //this line gives me a headache
             FileInputStream myFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);

             configStream = readMyStream(myFileInputStream);
               ..........
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw e;
         }
         return myConfig;
   }
   //reads the stream 
   private Config readMyStream(FileInputStream myFileInputStream) {
      Config config;    

      ...JDOM stuff....    

      return config;
   }
}
```

**The problems I face:**

- how to assert a File Object an FileInputStream (PowerMockito) like this File belongs to this FileInputStream with the following content
- how to mock a private method (Mockito/PowerMockito)

an example of the Mocking/not working :)....

```
public class ParserTest {

   @Test
   public final void testParse() {
      File MOCKEDFILE = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
      PowerMockito.when(MOCKEDFILE.exists()).thenReturn(true);
      PowerMockito.when(MOCKEDFILE.isFile()).thenReturn(true);
      PowerMockito.when(MOCKEDFILE.isDirectory()).thenReturn(false);
      PowerMockito.when(MOCKEDFILE.createNewFile()).thenReturn(true);
      PowerMockito.when(MOCKEDFILE.length()).thenReturn(11111111L);

      //what about the path of MOCKEDFILE which isn't existing
      PowerMockito.when(MOCKEDFILE.getPath()).thenReturn(?????);

      //how to assign a File an FileInputStream? (I thought something like)
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileInputStream.class);
      FileInputStream MOCKEDINPUTSTREAM = PowerMockito.mock(FileInputStream.class);
      PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withArguments(File.class).thenReturn(MOCKEDINPUTSTREAM);

      //how to mock the private method readMyStream
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than mocking `File`, I would suggest using the `TemporaryFolder` Rule and create / not create the file as appropriate.

In my previous projects, we have written a `FileInputStreamSupplier` class that is used to create a `FileInputStream`. This class can then be mocked to provide a mocked `FileInputStream` to allow for testing behavior. Generically, you could have your class take a `Supplier<FileInputStream>` (using Guava) and mock that.

Comment: could you please post an example code...I don't understand how the JUnit TemporaryFolder Rule should be related to my question.

Comment: You can use `TemporaryFolder` to create a `File` at runtime that matches the needs of the test, be it that the file exists (create it), has a particular name, extension, size, etc. Whan scenario are you attempting to test that would not be testable using this in conjunction with a `Supplier<FileInputStream>`?

Comment: I could write something like
`@Rule
   public TemporaryFolder tmpFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testParse_xyas() {
      File tmpFile = tmpFolder.newFile(FILENAME);
      //now how to assert my tmpFile an InputStream??
}..`

Comment: What do you mean be `assert my tmpFile an InputStream`? The file is not an InputStream. The InputStream will be created around the file in the line `new FileInputStream(file)`. If you need to mock `FileInputStream`, again use the Supplier I mention above.

Comment: Find this link pretty useful: [JUnit Rule Entity Manager](http://www.robert-franz.com/2013/03/26/junit-rule-entity-manager/)